# R : trouble while using lapply

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe. What I want to achieve is to have a column (representing months) coded on 2 characters (string of length 2) instead of an integer.

Here is a little sample of data :

```
wifi <- data.frame(replicate(2,8:12))
```

Which creates a dataframe like this :

```
   X1  X2
1   8   8
2   9   9
3  10  10
4  11  11
5  12  12
```

I want to have something like this :

```
   X1  X2
1   8  08
2   9  09
3  10  10
4  11  11
5  12  12
```

---

Here is the function I made :

```
A <- function(x) {
    if(nchar(x)==1) {
        return(paste0("0",x))
    } else {
        return(x)
    }
}
```

which seems to work as intended ( A("9") == "09" and A("12") == "12").

I tried this

```
cbind(wifi[1], lapply(wifi[2], A) )
```

Here is the result I got, it seems like this function is applied one time for all elements and not for each element.

```
   X1   X2
1   8   08
2   9   09
3  10  010
4  11  011
5  12  012
```

> Warning message:
>   In if (nchar(x) == 1) { :
>     the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Someone know I could fix that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would solve it using `sprintf()`

```
A <- function(x) {
  sprintf("%02d", x)
}

wifi[[2]] <- A(wifi[[2]])
wifi
  X1 X2
1  8 08
2  9 09
3 10 10
4 11 11
5 12 12
```

**But what's wrong with the current function?**

Almost nothing.

`if () {} else {}` deals with elements of length 1 and `lapply(wifi[2], A)` feeds it the whole vector. So you could do this with your original function using [different subsetting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-bracket-and-double-bracket-for-accessing-the-elem):

```
sapply(wifi[[2]], A)
```

However, perhaps better to go for the vectorised `ifelse()` and drop the `*apply()`:

```
A <- function(x) {
  x <- as.character(x)
  ifelse(nchar(x) == 1, paste0("0", x), x)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer, I have seen this ifelse thing before but now thanks to you I know what it is used for :)

Answer (score 2):

You should use the sprintf function instead.

This would apply it to all columns:

```
sapply(wifi, function(x) sprintf("%02.0f", x))
```

This only to the second one:

```
sprintf("%02.0f", wifi$X2)
```

`sprintf` is a built-in function to format strings (same as in C) and does exactly what you wanted your `A` function to do

It's better to use `sapply` for dataframes.